# $watch's object not triggered when attributes are changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have one object:

`$scope.obj = {bar: 'bar value', foo: 'foo value'};`

and I want to to know if bar, foo or both change.

I'm doing this:

`$scope.$watch('obj', function() { console.log("watching obj") });`

and If I change the object's attributes "watching obj" message It never shows. However, if I watch `'obj.foo'` or `'obj.bar'` I can see the message. So, the question is:

**Why the message isn't showing when I watch `'obj'`? and how can I do this?**

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Murf3LSSfQNOSD3Zd4Yk) shows the problem better...

Comment: By default, `$watch` only checks whether `$scope.obj` itself has changed. So, `$scope.obj = {};` would trigger the callback, but `$scope.obj.baz = {};` doesn't. The 3rd argument enables the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `objectEquality` argument to `true`.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

// $watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)

```
$scope.$watch('obj', function() {
    console.log("watching obj")
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just add to @moderndegree's answer,

If the object you want to watch has a few elements ( in this case only two) you can also use

```
$scope.$watch('obj.foo+obj.bar', function() {
    console.log("changed");
});
```

Which is more efficient than deep watching.